# Animate cc html canvas references MovieClip

Tags: html, html5-canvas, animate-cc

i'm trying to call a function in the root time line from an external script.
this is the function :

```
function myFunction(){
    this.mc.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

how can i call it from an external script in the html file?

Answer (score 0):

OK, two issues to knock out here.

One, as soon as this frame script runs, `function myFunction()` is created but never referenced, so it gets marked for garbage collection at the end of the script.  Which means you won't be able to access it again later.

So, since the point of this is being able to execute this code later, you will probably want to attach it to the root timeline by coding it like so:

```
this.myFunction = function(){
    this.mc.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

You can access myFunction from any other frame's script by typing `this.myFunction()`, so it should work just like it does in ActionScript, just with `this.` at the beginning.

Second part -- how do you run it?

Animate will create a `stage` object. The first and only child of the `stage` object is the main timeline, the DisplayObjectContainer that contains everything else. So, with the revised script above, we can reference it like so:

```
stage.children[0].myFunction();
```